# Terraform throwing error while trying to create Azure Databricks Cluster in a Landing Zone setup

Tags: azure, terraform, databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-azure

[image]I am trying to use Terraform to deploy Azure Databricks workspace and cluster. The workspace got created successfully along with the user group and i am able to login to Databricks successfully.
The problem i am having is while creating the cluster. Terraform apply fails after about 20 mins or so.
"public_network_access_enabled" is set to "True" in my terraform code for my workspace

If i look at the console of Azure DB, i see under Compute that the state is pending and it stays in pending state for around 20 mins and then everything disappears and terraform apply throws this error message below

Just for information we are operating in a landing zone and i have created two subnets for Databricks, one private and one public with /26
The vnet is peered to the hub vnet as it is in any landing zone.

```
[![1114-001756-9y2ijklp is not able to transition from TERMINATED to RUNNING: Instance was not reachable. This can be a transient networking issue. If the problem persists, this usually indicates a network environment misconfiguration. Please check your cloud provider config..., Termination info : code: INSTANCE_UNREACHABLE, type: , parameters: map\[databricks_error_message:
    Instance was not reachable.
    VM extension code: ProvisioningState/succeded
    instanceId: InstanceId(939d10dc729547c5bedb7cf32be7ecd1)
    workerEnv: workerenv-3791028417964786][1]][1]
```

Additional details (may be truncated):

The rest of the error is attached in the screenshot.

Just to inform, i tried logging in to Databricks interactively from the Azure portal and tried creating the cluster manually and it succeeds.
It succeeds means i can see the cluster at least which i wasn't able to see while trying to deploy using Terraform.
But the issue is when i try to start the cluster, it tries to start but after around 10 mins or so, it shows terminated

If i check the Event Log inside Databricks it says :

Cluster terminated.Reason: Instances unreachable

My Terraform Code:

```
resource "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "db-workspace" {
  name                          = module.names-db-workspace.environment.databricks_workspace.name_unique
  resource_group_name           = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.name
  location                      = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.location
  sku                           = "premium"
  public_network_access_enabled = true

  custom_parameters {
    no_public_ip                                         = false
    virtual_network_id                                   = module.virtualnetwork["centralus"].virtual_network.self.id
    public_subnet_name                                   = module.virtualnetwork["centralus"].virtual_network.subnets["db-sub-1-public"].name
    private_subnet_name                                  = module.virtualnetwork["centralus"].virtual_network.subnets["db-sub-2-private"].name
    public_subnet_network_security_group_association_id  = module.virtualnetwork["centralus"].virtual_network.nsgs.associations.subnets["databricks-public-nsg-db-sub-1-public"].id
    private_subnet_network_security_group_association_id = module.virtualnetwork["centralus"].virtual_network.nsgs.associations.subnets["databricks-private-nsg-db-sub-2-private"].id
  }
  tags = local.tags
}

resource "databricks_cluster" "dbcselfservice" {
  cluster_name            = format("adb-cluster-%s-%s", var.project.name, var.project.environment.name)
  spark_version           = var.spark_version
  node_type_id            = var.node_type_id
  autotermination_minutes = 20
  autoscale {
    min_workers = 1
    max_workers = 7
  }
  azure_attributes {
    availability       = "SPOT_AZURE"
    first_on_demand    = 1
    spot_bid_max_price = 100
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_databricks_workspace.db-workspace
  ]
}




locals {
  vnet = {
    enable = true
    subnets = {
      general = {
        cidrs   = [cidrsubnet(var.project.cidrs["centralus-default"][0], 2, 0)]
        private = { endpoint = true, service = false }
        service = { endpoints = [
          "Microsoft.KeyVault",
          "Microsoft.Storage",
          "Microsoft.Web",
          "Microsoft.EventHub",
          "Microsoft.Sql",
          "Microsoft.AzureCosmosDB"
          ],
          delegations = {}
        }
      }
      webapp = {
        cidrs   = [cidrsubnet(var.project.cidrs["centralus-default"][0], 2, 1)]
        private = { endpoint = false, service = false }
        service = { endpoints = [], delegations = {
          "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms" = {
            actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
            name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
          }
          }
        }
      }
      # waf = {
      #   cidrs   = [cidrsubnet(var.project.cidrs["centralus-default"][0], 4, 8)]
      #   private = { endpoint = false, service = false }
      #   service = { endpoints = [], delegations = {}
      #   }
      # }
      db-sub-1-public = {
        cidrs   = [cidrsubnet(var.project.cidrs["centralus-default"][0], 2, 2)]
        private = { endpoint = false, service = false }
        service = {
          endpoints = [],
          delegations = {
            "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces" = {
              actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/prepareNetworkPolicies/action"]
              name    = "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces"
            }
          }
        }
      }
      db-sub-2-private = {
        cidrs   = [cidrsubnet(var.project.cidrs["centralus-default"][0], 2, 3)]
        private = { endpoint = false, service = false }
        service = {
          endpoints = [],
          delegations = {
            "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces" = {
              actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/prepareNetworkPolicies/action"]
              name    = "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    asgs = {}
    nsgs = {
      databricks-public-nsg = {
        subnets = ["db-sub-1-public"]
        rules = {
          #   "databricks-worker-to-webapp" = {
          #     priority  = 101
          #     access    = "Allow"
          #     direction = "Outbound"
          #     protocol  = "tcp"
          #     destination = {
          #       ports  = ["443"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "AzureDatabricks"
          #     }
          #     source = {
          #       ports  = ["*"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
          #     }
          #   }
          #   "databricks-worker-to-storage" = {
          #     priority  = 104
          #     access    = "Allow"
          #     direction = "Outbound"
          #     protocol  = "tcp"
          #     destination = {
          #       ports  = ["443"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "Storage"
          #     }
          #     source = {
          #       ports  = ["*"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
          #     }
          #   }
          #   "databricks-worker-to-sql" = {
          #     priority  = 106
          #     access    = "Allow"
          #     direction = "Outbound"
          #     protocol  = "tcp"
          #     destination = {
          #       ports  = ["3306"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "Sql"
          #     }
          #     source = {
          #       ports  = ["*"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
          #     }
          #   }
          #   "databricks-worker-within-cluster" = {
          #     priority  = 100
          #     access    = "Allow"
          #     direction = "Inbound"
          #     protocol  = "tcp"
          #     destination = {
          #       ports  = ["*"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
          #     }
          #     source = {
          #       ports  = ["*"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
          #     }
          #   }
          #   "databricks-worker-within-cluster" = {
          #     priority  = 108
          #     access    = "Allow"
          #     direction = "Outbound"
          #     protocol  = "tcp"
          #     destination = {
          #       ports  = ["*"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
          #     }
          #     source = {
          #       ports  = ["*"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
          #     }
          #   }
          #   "databricks-worker-to-event-hubs" = {
          #     priority  = 110
          #     access    = "Allow"
          #     direction = "Outbound"
          #     protocol  = "tcp"
          #     destination = {
          #       ports  = ["9093"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "Eventhubs"
          #     }
          #     source = {
          #       ports  = ["*"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
          #     }
        }
      }
      databricks-private-nsg = {
        subnets = ["db-sub-2-private"]
        rules = {
          #   "databricks-worker-to-webapp" = {
          #     priority  = 101
          #     access    = "Allow"
          #     direction = "Outbound"
          #     protocol  = "tcp"
          #     destination = {
          #       ports  = ["443"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "AzureDatabricks"
          #     }
          #     source = {
          #       ports  = ["*"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
          #     }
          #   }
          #   "databricks-worker-to-storage" = {
          #     priority  = 104
          #     access    = "Allow"
          #     direction = "Outbound"
          #     protocol  = "tcp"
          #     destination = {
          #       ports  = ["443"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "Storage"
          #     }
          #     source = {
          #       ports  = ["*"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
          #     }
          #   }
          #   "databricks-worker-to-sql" = {
          #     priority  = 106
          #     access    = "Allow"
          #     direction = "Outbound"
          #     protocol  = "tcp"
          #     destination = {
          #       ports  = ["3306"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "Sql"
          #     }
          #     source = {
          #       ports  = ["*"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
          #     }
          #   }
          #   "databricks-worker-within-cluster" = {
          #     priority  = 100
          #     access    = "Allow"
          #     direction = "Inbound"
          #     protocol  = "tcp"
          #     destination = {
          #       ports  = ["*"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
          #     }
          #     source = {
          #       ports  = ["*"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
          #     }
          #   }
          #   "databricks-worker-within-cluster" = {
          #     priority  = 108
          #     access    = "Allow"
          #     direction = "Outbound"
          #     protocol  = "tcp"
          #     destination = {
          #       ports  = ["*"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
          #     }
          #     source = {
          #       ports  = ["*"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
          #     }
          #   }
          #   "databricks-worker-to-event-hubs" = {
          #     priority  = 110
          #     access    = "Allow"
          #     direction = "Outbound"
          #     protocol  = "tcp"
          #     destination = {
          #       ports  = ["9093"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "Eventhubs"
          #     }
          #     source = {
          #       ports  = ["*"]
          #       asgs   = []
          #       prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
          #     }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

 module "virtualnetwork" {
  version                         = "~> 7.0"
  source                          = "contoso.com/virtual-network/azurerm"
  for_each                        = (local.vnet.enable) ? { centralus = "Central US" } : {}
  providers                       = { azurerm = azurerm, azurerm.hub = azurerm.hub, random = random }
  hub_resource_group_name         = var.project.hub.resourcegroup.name
  hub_virtual_hub_name            = var.project.hub.virtualhub.name
  hub_ddos_protection_plan_name   = var.project.hub.ddosprotectionplan.name
  resource_group_name             = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.name
  virtual_network_location        = each.value
  virtual_network_environment     = var.project.environment.name
  virtual_network_name            = var.project.name
  virtual_network_tags            = module.resourcegroup.resource_group.tags
  virtual_network_cidrs           = var.project.cidrs[format("%s-default", each.key)]
  virtual_network_subnets         = local.vnet.subnets
  application_security_groups     = local.vnet.asgs
  virtual_network_security_groups = local.vnet.nsgs
}
```

Comment: hello @Pallab could you please add the code that you are using to create the resources?

Comment: it's a clear indication that it something wrong with your networking setup. Compare your code against this workspace setup: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/main/examples/databricks/secure-connectivity-cluster/without-load-balancer/main.tf

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MTAdded the code now in the main thread. There is no NSG rule defined so to speak. But NSG just created and association made to the Public and Private subnets of /26

Comment: Quick update. After i changed the "no_public_ip" to true under workspace custom parameters, the cluster was successfully deployed. So i would like to understand that for a VNET injected workspace, why the cluster creation fails if you make this to false?